# (PHP)Script in Apache works great, but not in IIS

Tags: php, apache, iis

I didn't know wrote what in Title, sorry!
I have this script that I got from [MediaDivision](http://www.media-division.com/php-download-script-with-resume-option/) for **downloading data** with header:

```
<?php
// hide notices
@ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);

//- turn off compression on the server
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

//Getting upload center and append file name

$file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $dir_path;
$file_name = pathinfo($file_path)['basename'];

// allow a file to be streamed instead of sent as an attachment
$is_attachment = isset($_REQUEST['stream']) ? false : true;

// make sure the file exists
if (is_file($file_path))
{
    $file_size  = filesize($file_path);
    $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
    if ($file)
    {
        // set the headers, prevent caching
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: -1");
        header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$file_name\"");
        header("Content-Type: video/x-msvideo");
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        {
            list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
            {
                list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                $range = '';
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                exit;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }

        //figure out download piece from range (if set)
        list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

        //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
        //also check for invalid ranges.
        $seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
        $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

        //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
        if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
            header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
        }
        else
          header("Content-Length: $file_size");

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        set_time_limit(0);
        fseek($file, $seek_start);
 
        while(!feof($file)) 
        {
            print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            if (connection_status()!=0) 
            {
                @fclose($file);
                exit;
            }           
        }

        // file save was a success
        @fclose($file);
        exit;
    }
    else 
    {
        // file couldn't be opened
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    // file does not exist
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
?>
```

This script works great in `Linux` servers that I tested with. I can **resume downloads** and get **8 connection** in `IDM` and everything, But is `IIS` I just get **1 connection** and after every pause, I have to wait a few seconds or I get `Server Closed Connection`.
I have exact `php` version installed in both servers, And did all the configs that I found in tutorials with `Windows Server 2012` and `IIS 8`.
So what's the problem here?
*(Although I have to say that direct download from `Server 2012` has no problem and works great.)*
**Edit:**
I test the script on windows server with `Nginx` too, but same as `IIS`, It doesn't work right.